# How do I change "&nbsp;" characters to normal spaces in R

Tags: html, r, string, stringr

I am using R for web scraping and I have a script that copies the text of a link and then uses this string to follow the link using RSelenium. Unfortunately this does not seem to work for one particular string when I run the script, but when I replace the saved string with a manually typed string it works fine. A little digging into the html of the page reveals that one of the space characters is actually a   character and this is why the string is failing to match. How to I replace   with a normal space in R? I have tried using the stringr library and the str_replace command as follows:

```
var1 <- str_replace(var1, pattern = "&nbsp;", " ")
```

But this does not appear to work. Is there anything I am obviously doing wrong? And is there a way to get R to display a string with all the weird formatting characters visible?

Comment: your code works for me..

Comment: If it doesn't work, you should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and be clear on what exactly "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have realised that I should have used str_replace_all() rather than str_replace(). MrFlick - I could not create a reproducible example because the page I was scraping required a log in and I could not find a way to copy the string into my post and show the actual &nbsp; character since the print() function represents it as a normal space. I would be grateful if you knew of a way to do this for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

You need the `\u00A0` as replace char
so `var1 <- gsub("\u00A0", "", var1, fixed =TRUE)`